# Detecting connection closure with Comet and Play Framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, comet

I use the function below icm an iframe to run a very long process (the system looks for duplicate records, it is only a read operation).

However, if the user has the record they need and leave the page the process continues. Is there a way to detect and terminate the process when this happens?

I expected the `public void onDisconnected(F.Callback0 callback0)` to be called, but that does not seem the case.

```
public static Result findDuplicatesActor(){
    Comet comet = new Comet("parent.cometMessage") {
      public void onConnected() {
          int totalRecords = User.find.findRowCount();
          int processed = 0;
          int progress;
          for(User user : User.find.all()){
              progress = Math.round(((float) processed / (float) totalRecords * 100));                 
              sendMessage("{\"progress\":" + progress + ",\"result\":\"OK\"}");
              Logger.info("Progress on duplicate search: " + progress);
              processed++;
          }

          sendMessage("{\"progress\":100,\"result\":\"OK\"}");
          close();
      }

        @Override
        public void close() {
            Logger.info("Connection closed!");
            super.close();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(F.Callback0 callback0) {
            Logger.info("Connection disconnected!");
            super.onDisconnected(callback0);
        }
    };

    return ok(comet);
}
```